# A function for determining whether a series of points and a series polygons intersect

Tags: r, function, r-sf

I have a list of points and a list of polygons, and I wish to find the polygon each point locates in. Though it is straightforward to use the command `st_intersects` in `sf` package, I find that is not good here since both the points and polygons are so many that the resulting matrix is too big for my computer to work.

I try to get around this by making a function, which can look through all the polygons to find the right one for each point. I made one but it did not work well and I have had no idea what is the problem with it. So I need some help! Thanks!

The following is how I create the list of points

```
pts = st_sfc(st_point(c(.5,.5)), st_point(c(1.5, 1.5)), st_point(c(2.5, 
2.5))) %>% st_sf() %>% mutate(namepoint=c(1,2,3))

Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.5 ymin: 0.5 xmax: 2.5 ymax: 2.5
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
   namepoint        geometry
1         1 POINT (0.5 0.5)
2         2 POINT (1.5 1.5)
3         3 POINT (2.5 2.5)
```

The following is how I create the list of polygons

```
pol_down = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,0), c(2,0), c(2,2), c(0,2), c(0,0))))
pol_up=pol_down+c(2,1) 
pol_add <- list(pol_down,pol_up) %>% st_sfc() %>% st_sf %>% 
mutate(namepgn=c('A','B'))

Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 4 ymax: 3
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
   namepgn                       geometry
1       A POLYGON ((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 ...
2       B POLYGON ((2 1, 4 1, 4 3, 2 ...
```

The function I made is

```
 fun_pgn <- function(x,y){
                location_m<- st_intersects(x,
                                           y,
                                           sparse = F)
                name <- pull(y,1) %>% .[location_m]
                return(name)
             }
```

Use the command `st_intersects` to get the their relations

```
st_intersects(pts,pol,sparse = F)

      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
```

Then what I want is to add a variable,like `pgnname` in the data `pts` to record the polygon for each point,

```
        namepoint    pgnname    geometry
1               1       "A"     POINT (0.5 0.5)
2               2       "A"     POINT (1.5 1.5)
3               3       "B"     POINT (2.5 2.5)
```

However my function does not work. After running the following codes

```
pts %>% mutate(pgnname=fun_pgn(geometry,pol))
```

it follows

```
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.5 ymin: 0.5 xmax: 2.5 ymax: 2.5
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  namepoint pgnname        geometry
1         1       A POINT (0.5 0.5)
2         2       B POINT (1.5 1.5)
3         3    <NA> POINT (2.5 2.5)
```

The names of polygons are incorrect! But the key part of my function works well. For example

```
> pull(pol,1) %>% .[st_intersects(pts[3,],pol,sparse = F)]
[1] "B"
```

So I'm confused. What happens when I run my functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you can't use `st_intersects` because "the resulting matrix is too big for my computer".  The simplest solution for this is to not generate a dense matrix, which you force by using `sparse = F`.  The default behaviour of `st_intersects` without this argument is to generate a sparse list, which is what you are trying to do with your function.

```
x = st_intersects(pts, pol)
pts %>% mutate(pgnname = pol$namepgn[unlist(x)])
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
# geometry type:  POINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 0.5 ymin: 0.5 xmax: 2.5 ymax: 2.5
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
#   namepoint pgnname        geometry
# 1         1       A POINT (0.5 0.5)
# 2         2       A POINT (1.5 1.5)
# 3         3       B POINT (2.5 2.5)
```

Note that, in case of the possibility that a point could fall in more than one polygon, and you only want to assign a single polygon to that point, you can use the following instead:

```
pgn = sapply(x, `[`, 1)
pts %>% mutate(pgnname = pol$namepgn[pgn])
```

Comment: Thanks！It works except that there are "empty" values or more than one values for one point. That is there are no polygons or more than one polygons contains a certain point. In these cases, after `unlist` command does not produce the right location. I want to report NA for no polygon case and report the first polygon for the case of more than one polygons.

Comment: The 2nd part of my answer addresses exactly those issues.  Have you tested the `pgn = sapply(x, `[`, 1)` version?

Comment: And I still want to learn what's wrong with my function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! The second part really can  address those issues!